# Ubuntu 12.04 won't shut down - stopping winbind daemon

Tags: 12.04, shutdown

My Precise Pangolin sometimes won't shut down - the screen is black with text on it. Mostly last line says something like `stopping winbind deamon` (sometimes also virtualbox, which is above winbind daemon;)

Edit: sometimes the last line says `running unattended updates`.

And it stays like this for about ten miutes. Then I usually hold the power button for more than 5 seconds to shut it down. It's very unpredictable. Sometimes the computer shuts down without problem and sometimes it hangs.

I've tried many ways to shut it down: HW button, panel applet, `sudo shutdown -h now`, `sudo poweroff`, `sudo halt`, etc. Even i tried `sudo reboot` or `restart` from panel applet. They also have this problem. Sometimes it works correctly. But every method named hung at least once on the same (damned) line.

My specs:

> - FUJITSU SIEMENS LIFEBOOK E8310,
> - Intel Core2 Duo T7300 @ 2.00GHz,
> - 3GB RAM,
> - GPU: Mobile Intel(R) 965 Express Chipset Family
> - Ubuntu 12.04.2 32bit, 3.5.0-41-generic kernel (but it did it on older kernels and 12.04.x systems too).

Any ideas what should I try next?

Comment: This happens to me but only for about 30 seconds (it doesn't vary as the time of yours does). I have the same version, just 64 bit; a Toshiba Satellite Pro with Intel Core i3, 4 GB of RAM, and I think the kernel version (on `/proc/version signature`) is `3.8.0-32.47~precise1-generic`. The rest of what you mentioned is the same (it doesn't depend on shutdown method, etc.).

Comment: There was no variation in time - when it hung, it was forever (or until I forced it to shut down by holding the power button). And I'm saying "was" because I did a fresh install of 13.10 and the whole problem is gone (also flash plays much better, no yellow dots anymore). I went for Saucy since there is gonna be LTS on April so I could handle this as a small adventure before settling again with next LTS ;)

Comment: good, then you're fine now. I'm investigating into it, but I won't install newer Ubuntu versions. I'll use Arch Linux with XMonad, it's awesomly fast. You can try other desktop environments/window managers on Ubuntu simply installing them: try DWM (or XMonad), Xfce, KDE, and Gnome (google install <name-of-the-wm>).

Comment: I tried many of them (really liked XFCE and LXDE) but later I realized Unity suits me best :) I even took a look at Mint's MATE and Cinnamon but they can't compare to Unity (in my eyes). And Unity is also much faster in 13.10 than in 12.04 ;)
I just hope Canonical won't screw up Unity because I see nowhere else to go (for now).

Comment: In Mint I only tried KDE (in a VM), before I came from Windows. I hadn't heard it is faster yet (it is indeed slow in 12.04), but I don't care anymore, see [this](https://www.fsf.org/blogs/rms/ubuntu-spyware-what-to-do). This compromises one of the reasons I came to Linux, so as I said, I'm changing to Arch. But you've got to try XMonad (I'm using it right now in Ubuntu).